# Random Sample of Cases For Multiple Case Handlers

Tags: sql, postgresql, random, greatest-n-per-group, sample

In a PostgreSQL database, I have an extract of cases worked in any given month by all of the case handlers. I need to randomly select 4 cases per case handler to complete a check. Is there any way to do this in SQL?

Assuming the database is called `casemanagement` and the table is called `cases`, I would expect the query to obtain the full extract without the random sample to be something along the lines of:

```
SELECT a.case_id, a.case_handler, a.case_status
FROM casemanagement.cases a
WHERE a.case_status = 'Completed'
ORDER BY a.case_id;
```

If I were to add in a condition for a random sample with a limit, I assume the following would work for an individual case handler:

```
SELECT a.case_id, a.case_handler, a.case_status
FROM casemanagement.cases a
WHERE a.case_status = 'Completed' and a.case_handler = 'John Smith'
ORDER BY RANDOM()
LIMIT 4
```

But is it possible to have the limit of 4 without having to specify the case handler in the where function?

Comment: About: *"Assuming the database is called `casemanagement`"*. You are confusing "database" with "schema". See: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-schemas.html

Comment: Yes apologies, I did mean schema, as I said I’m a very basic user so not too familiar with the terminology!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you also have a table `case_handler` with one row per case handler of interest (like you should!)

Then a `LATERAL` subquery does the job:

```sql
SELECT h.case_handler, c.case_id, c.case_status
FROM   casemanagement.case_handler h
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT c.case_id, c.case_status
   FROM   casemanagement.cases c
   WHERE  c.case_handler = h.case_handler
   AND    c.case_status = 'Completed'
   ORDER  BY random()
   LIMIT  4
   ) c ON true;
```

See:

- [What is the difference between a LATERAL JOIN and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-a-lateral-join-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)

Assuming `case_handler.case_handler` to be the `PRIMARY KEY`. Adapt to your actual design.

The index associated with the PK can also help performance, if an index-only scan is possible. More importantly: have an index on `casemanagement.cases(case_handler)`. For large tables and/or few  'Completed' cases, more optimization is possible.

If you don't have a table `case_handler`, consider creating it.
Or distill it for the purpose of this query alone in a CTE:

```sql
WITH case_handler AS (
   SELECT DISTINCT case_handler FROM casemanagement.cases
   )
SELECT h.case_handler, c.case_id, c.case_status
FROM   case_handler h ... -- rest like above
```

For many rows per handler, there are faster query styles to get distinct rows. See:

- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest row per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536422/optimize-group-by-query-to-retrieve-latest-row-per-user/25536748#25536748)